# How to add text and image in a column in Component One FlexGrid?

Tags: c#-4.0, using, componentone, c1flexgrid

I have used the below mentioned snippet to show text with image. However I am unable to display image with it.

Is the path to image not accessible from code?

```
C1.Win.C1FlexGrid.C1FlexGrid gAuditL = new C1.Win.C1FlexGrid.C1FlexGrid();
.
.
.
gAuditL.DataSource = AuditLogVieweryDT;// this is datasource
for (int i = gAuditL.Row.Fixed; i < gAuditL.Rows.Count; i++)
//foreach  row in grid 
{
 string severity = gAuditL[i, gAuditL.Cols["Severity"].Index].ToString();
 if (severity == "Information")
 {
   this.gAuditL.SetCellImage(i, 0,Image.FromFile(@".\\Resources\information.bmp"));
   this.gAuditL.SetData(i, 0, "Information");
 }
 if (severity == "Warning")
 {
   this.gAuditL.SetCellImage(i, 0, Image.FromFile(@".\\Resources\warning.bmp"));
   this.gAuditL.SetData(i, 0, "Warning");
 }
 if (severity == "Critical")
 {
   this.gAuditL.SetCellImage(i, 0, Image.FromFile(@".\\Resources\critical.bmp"));
   this.gAuditL.SetData(i, 0, "Critical");
 }
 if (severity == "Unspecified")
 {
   this.gAuditL.SetCellImage(i, 0, Image.FromFile(@".\\Resources\unspecified.bmp"));
   this.gAuditL.SetData(i, 0, "Unspecified");
 }

 this.gAuditL.Styles.Normal.ImageAlign = C1.Win.C1FlexGrid.ImageAlignEnum.LeftCenter;
 this.gAuditL.Styles.Normal.TextAlign = C1.Win.C1FlexGrid.TextAlignEnum.RightCenter;
}
```

Comment: Not sure if \\Resources directory is accessible to your code. Try using **var currentDirectory = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();**

Comment: hi Nilay Vishwakarma,this code worked for me , offcourse we can use genral path like c:/temp/resource/images

Comment: I would recommend you to reach the componentone vendors site for quicker response. [http://our.componentone.com/groups/](http://our.componentone.com/groups/). Provide a zipped sample and you would get the response. Also enlighten all of us with the answer (from ComponentOne Forums) by posting here.

Comment: What was the error here?

Comment: it was not showing image only text was displaying

Comment: now i know how to get it done but am not able to post my answer here  some thing we are no more take answer error is displaying

Comment: Edit your Question add a new section at the end named answer

Comment: Was there no provision to add images and text without using OwnerDrawnCells?

Comment: hi Nilay Vishwakarma,am not able to post answer or ask question i need to come out from ban what steps i need to perform???

Comment: Question Ban and Answer Ban

Comment: Please refer [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255584/3331861) and [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251113/i-cant-ask-questions-on-stack-overflow?rq=1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer this.(**Answer posted by OP**)

```
namespace SampleProject.Forms.Maintenance
{

public partial class SampleProject: Form
{

    Image img1, img2, img3, img4;// declare member variable

    //Load Event
      private void AuditLogViewer_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        object information = Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject("information"); //Return an object from the image chan1.png in the project
        img1 = (Image)information;
        object Warning = Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject("warning"); //Return an object from the image chan1.png in the project
        img2 = (Image)Warning;
        object critical = Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject("critical"); //Return an object from the image chan1.png in the project
        img3 = (Image)critical;
        object unspecified = Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject("unspecified"); //Return an object from the image chan1.png in the project
        img4 = (Image)unspecified;
    }

 //Grid Click Event
    private void grdAuditLogs_OwnerDrawCell(object sender, OwnerDrawCellEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Col == 2)
        {
            //let the grid paint the background and border for the cell
            e.DrawCell(C1.Win.C1FlexGrid.DrawCellFlags.Background | C1.Win.C1FlexGrid.DrawCellFlags.Border);

            //find text width
            var width = (int)e.Graphics.MeasureString(e.Text, e.Style.Font).Width;

            //x-coordinate for each image
            var img1_x = e.Bounds.X + width + 10;
            var img2_x = e.Bounds.X + width + 10;
            var img3_x = e.Bounds.X + width + 10;
            var img4_x = e.Bounds.X + width + 10;

            //var img3_x = img2_x + img2.Width + 5;

            //location for each image
            var img1_loc = new Point(img1_x, e.Bounds.Y + img1.Height - 18);
            var img2_loc = new Point(img2_x, e.Bounds.Y + img2.Height - 18);
            var img3_loc = new Point(img3_x, e.Bounds.Y + img3.Height - 18);
            var img4_loc = new Point(img4_x, e.Bounds.Y + img4.Height - 18);


            //draw images at aforementioned points
            if (grdAuditLogs[e.Row, grdAuditLogs.Cols["Severity"].Index].ToString() == "Information")
                e.Graphics.DrawImage(img1, img1_loc);
            if (grdAuditLogs[e.Row, grdAuditLogs.Cols["Severity"].Index].ToString() == "Warning")
                e.Graphics.DrawImage(img2, img2_loc);
            if (grdAuditLogs[e.Row, grdAuditLogs.Cols["Severity"].Index].ToString() == "Critical")
                e.Graphics.DrawImage(img3, img3_loc);
            if (grdAuditLogs[e.Row, grdAuditLogs.Cols["Severity"].Index].ToString() == "Unspecified")
                e.Graphics.DrawImage(img4, img4_loc);

            //e1.Graphics.DrawImage(img3, img3_loc);

            //draw text
            e.Graphics.DrawString(e.Text, e.Style.Font, Brushes.Black, e.Bounds.Location);
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: @Deepthi Krishna - you can answer your own question by posting an answer. But don't do it in the description.

Comment: @AndreyPopov It seems like OP is banned from posting answers and question. Refer comments in the question post

Comment: hi @AndreyPopov, am in ban zone so i can't post